# Tapestry 5.3: PlasticClass.getMethods doesn't include introduced methods

Tags: java, tapestry

Recently we updated all our ComponentClassTransformWorkers to ComponentClassTransformWorker2s and came across a bug. So, to create a method a new ComponentClassTransformWorker2 called, say, **LukesComponentClassTransformWorker2** I use something like this:

```
PlasticMethod plasticMethod = plasticClass.introduceMethod("defaultValidate");
MethodAdvice advice = new MethodAdvice(){
    @Override
    public void advise(MethodInvocation invocation) {
        invocation.proceed();
        environment.push(MenuContext.class, context);   
    }
};
plasticMethod.addAdvice(advice);
```

Then when a later worker (in my case, Tapestry's built in ParameterWorker) looks for this using PlasticClass.getMethods() and doesn't find it as plasticClass.getMethods() doesn't return any 'introduced' methods.

This change will even break implementations of the deprecated ComponentClassTransformationWorker because **BridgeClassTransformation** simply uses PlasticClass.getMethods() under the hood:

```
public List<TransformMethod> matchMethods(Predicate<TransformMethod> predicate)
{
    return F.flow(plasticClass.getMethods()).map(toTransformMethod).filter(predicate).toList();
}
```

This seems like a bug to me as it is a breaking change and it seems to apply to fields too. Shouldn't searching for a method/field on a class include any introduced methods/fields too?